# what to do if data access layer dll throws 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in Unknown Module

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oracle11g

In my project data access layer throws exception

> An unhandled exception of type System.AccessViolationException
>   occurred in Unknown Module. Attempted to read or write protected
>   memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. I
>   added breakpoint and got this error CS0103: The name '$exception' does
>   not exist in the current context in watch1.

My code is below

```
    Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
    DbCommand objComm = db.GetStoredProcCommand("packagename.spname", new object[1]);
```

`Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();` in this line i got stuck and when i continue debug my syatem crashes and gives IIS express worker process stopped working.You will find below link is my problem details

[link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47939013/database-db-databasefactory-createdatabasename-databasename-oracle-store-pr)

I need help regarding this. Anybody have any info regarding this?

Comment: Access Violation is symptom of problem in unmanaged code rather than .Net or ASP.NET., It would be helpful to post a list of packages and components you're using in this project outside of the .NET framework.  Are you using Oracle DB?  What package are you using to access that?

Comment: yes it's oracle db. In my project oracle data provider is system.data.oracleClient. should i use Oracle.DataAccess or Oracle.DataManagedAccess instead?will that solve this problem?i just found out that createdatabase this namespace is deprecated for ages.this is written top of my project page                                        using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data;
I am kinda a new in asp.net and oracle .